# Opening New Terminal Tab Moves Window Above Dock

Tags: terminal, dock, high-sierra, tabs

This is difficult to explain, so please bear with me.

When I open a new tab in Terminal, the Terminal window moves. This only happens when the window is at the bottom of the screen. The window moves up vertically just enough so that it is not below/beside the dock anymore. It does not move horizontally. It also remains the same size.

No other apps behave this way, **only Terminal**. I am using version 2.8.

Terminal did not behave this way in macOS 10.12 Sierra. It started behaving this way when I updated to **10.13.1 High Sierra**.

Step by step, this is what happens:

1. Open Terminal.
2. Move Terminal window to **bottom left or right corner** of screen *(flush with the edges)*.
3. Open **new tab** in Terminal.
4. Terminal **window moves up** so that it is higher than the dock.

How do I prevent #4 from happening? How do I prevent the Terminal window from moving by itself when I open a new tab?

---

#### Before

[image: Before]

---

#### After

[image: After]

Comment: Interesting. I can reproduce this, but I've found that it's not limited to the bottom of the screen (though this is where it most noticeable). Regardless of the location of the Terminal window, if a second tab is opened, it shrinks in size by shifting the bottom of the window up slightly. You can see this easily by typing ⌘T and ⌘W repetitively to open and close the second tab.

This is likely a bug in Terminal.

Comment: Also see: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55280/opening-tab-in-terminal-resizes-window

Comment: There is a bit of a workaround - if you select the option to `Show Tab Bar` under the View Menu, then the Tab Bar is not created when you create the 2nd tab, so the window does not shift.

Comment: @Scot That does not change the behavior on my computer unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm - did you try activating `Show Tab Bar`, then making a new window (there should now be a tab bar with a single Tab). Then making a new Tab?

When I do this, the window does not shrink.

Comment: @Scot I tried that with no luck. `Show Tab Bar` is my normal setting too.

Comment: Hmm - perhaps there are multiple issues. For what its worth, I'm using High Sierra 10.13.2, and Terminal v2.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to macOS, windows should not be behind the Dock. When the bounds of a window are updated, macOS moves any windows from behind the Dock above the Dock.

The window bounds update when you add a new tab, so macOS looks at those bounds and moves them such that they don't overlap with the Dock section of the screen. There's no way to change this currently.

As for why this happens in High Sierra and not in Sierra, I presume it's because Terminal now uses the unified tabs functionality provided in AppKit.

Terminal has always had tabs, but macOS recently introduced tabs as part of the OS, for any app to use. I believe Terminal now uses this functionality for its tabs, which has caused this. You can test this by opening Terminal with multiple tabs and pressing ⇧⌘\ for Show All Tabs — this is functionality provided system-wide by the OS, not by Terminal, for managing tabs including the tab bar.