# How to prevent Terminal window from changing its size after opening and closing tab

Tags: macos, terminal, bug

Each time I open and close new tab in *Terminal* app, the size of window "shrinks" by one line, until it reaches 5 lines, where it stops shrinking at last.

I can literally keep repeating sequence <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to reproduce this any time.

I have tried changing *Terminal* settings, font family and font size, but nothing helped. Is there anything that can be done to prevent this?

**Note:** this question is ***not*** a duplicate of [Opening tab in Terminal resizes window](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55280/opening-tab-in-terminal-resizes-window).

Comment: Have you tried submitting a feedback to Apple?

Comment: Technically, it is related. It is just not a duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to **turn on setting to always show tab bar**, even if only one tab is open in window:

- in top bar, go to `View` → `Show Tab Bar`,
- or use keyboard shortcut <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

This is just a workaround I have found on [this site](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090729181510702) to a bug that is present in Terminal app at least since 2009. So far this is the only solution that was working for me consistently on every OS X installation.

Comment: As of macOS High Sierra (10.13.4), this still remains an issue. Even with this solution applied, Terminal window will shrink at least a little bit when fully stretched vertically (hidden Dock).

Comment: Unfortunately, for splitting pane this solution falls short too.

Comment: I don't have this option on Windows.

Comment: @aderchox what do you mean "on Windows"? This is a macOS-related question and you are on a site dedicated to  Apple-related problems 

Comment: @FurloSK Oh thank you, I was searching for just the exact same thing for VSCode.

Comment: In iTerm2 you accomplish that with `Preferences -> Appearance -> Tabs -> Either of the first 2 options should work`

Answer (score 1):

1. Window > Save Windows as Group...
2. Preferences > General > On startup, open : Window group, select the item that you just saved.

after these actions, the Terminal could keep window size, but if you open a new terminal window, you will get a default window size of it, finish follow steps to work out it:

3. Preferences > General > New windows open with: Same profile
4. Preferences > General > New tabs open with: Same profile

Done.

it works on macos 12.5

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the version 3.4.16 and I found the following option to always show the tab bar:

[image: Iterm preferences]

This solves the problem described in the question.

Comment: Does this solve the problem described in the question?

Comment: Yes, it does, because the terminal window, by default, changes its size when you have goes from 1 to 2 tabs because it starts to shows this "tab bar". With this option checked, it will always show the tab bar and the size will not change anymore.

Comment: Maybe you should add that to the answer. Currently it reads like the answer to a "how can I force the tab bar to show always" question.

Comment: What version of macOS is this? It would help more than stating version of Terminal app. As far as I understand, your answer is the same as mine, just the place where the setting (to always show tab bar) is located has changed. I can add this to my answer if you give me the macOS version.

Comment: I'm running 12.5.1

Comment: I believe @FabioPerrella is sharing the settings for iTerm, not Terminal. His preference tabs match those as documented by the iTerm site: https://iterm2.com/documentation-preferences.html

Meanwhile, the version of Terminal in Sonoma 14.0 is 2.14.